# Determine the sign of $\lambda^2/(k-1)-2\lambda/k$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}-\{1\}, 0\leq\lambda\leq1$

Tags: inequality

I was given a polynomial $\frac{\lambda^2}{k-1}-\frac{2\lambda}{k}$ where $k$ is an integer greater than 1, and $\lambda\in[0,1]$. I computationally simulated that it is less than or equal to 0, but have few ideas about how to show it without codes. How can I say that its sign is (-)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your polynomial is $0$ at $\lambda = 0$ and $2 - 2/k$ (which  $\ge 1$ for $k \le 1$).
When $\lambda$ is small and positive, the linear term dominates so the value is negative.  Therefore it is negative on the whole interval $(0, 2 - 2/k)$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment professor, so in other words ii) it is zero if $\lambda = 0$ or $k=2$; ii) for other cases the whole polynomial is dominated by the linear term so that it is negative? Did I understand correctly? Could you suggest if I can re-write into a Big-O notation? I first thought that then it is $\mathcal{O}(0),$ which looks a little bit weird.

Comment: You appear to misunderstand completely.  Your polynomial is $0$ at $\lambda = 0$ and at $\lambda = 2 - 2/k$.  Between those two values of $\lambda$, its sign is constant.

Comment: Now I got it . Thank you!